# Seleccionar en que celda imprimir Excel VBA

Tags: vba

¿De que manera puedo elegir en que celda imprimir el txt que mando a llamar?, por defecto se imprime en la primera (A1)

¿Se podría mandar a llamar a otro .txt?, por ejemplo, "prueba.txt" que salga en la A2, "prueba2.txt" en B2 y así...

Son 4 txt que me gustaria juntar en el mismo documento

```html
Sub ImportarTxt()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim fn As Integer
Dim Cadena As String
Dim Ruta As String
Dim arr

fn = FreeFile
Ruta = "C:\xampp2\htdocs\Casino_Macao\ALOFT\contadores\contador_concierge.txt"

Open Ruta For Input As #fn

Do While Not EOF(fn)
    Line Input #fn, Cadena
    i = i + 1
    arr = Split(Cadena, ";")
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j + 1).Value = arr(j)
    Next j
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu código tienes este bucle para los datos:

`For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j + 1).Value = arr(j)
    Next j`

Las variables `i` y `j` se inicializan a valor 0. Luego a i le sumas 1.

Así que la primera vez que se ejecuta tu bucle, estás diciendo la celda A1, luego la celda B1, luego C1.

Tienes que jugar con `i` y con `j` para adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Por cierto, cuando definas variables, especifica siempre el tipo o VBA las crea como `Variant`.

Por ejemplo, tienes `Dim i, j As Integer`, y ahí solamente `j` se está creando como `Integer`. `i` se está creando como `Variant`. Lo correcto sería:

`Dim i as Integer, j As Integer`.

Y otro consejo. En Excel para filas, mejor usar `Long`, para evitar errores de desbordamiento.